# Count Number of Uppercase and Lowercase Letters in a string in C

Tags: c, string, count, char, int

I want to create a code that finds the number of Uppercase and Lowercase letters. So for example

```
input:
HelloGUYS
Output:
4 5
```

What I have of code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int i, longitud;
int X[26];
char line[1010];

for(i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    X[i] = 0;
}

while(gets(line))
{
   longitud = strlen(line);

   for(i=0; i<longitud; i++)
   {
      if(line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z')
      {
        X[line[i] - 'a']++;
      }
      else if(line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z')
      {
        X[line[i] - 'A']++;
      }
   }
}

for(i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    printf("%c: %d\n", i+'a' , X[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

The thing is that my program does not work, I don't know what is the problem. I really aprreciate the help. Thanks :)

Comment: Please define *"does not work"*.

Comment: I think the problem is your code is trying to solve a different problem! It's counting the number of times each letter A to Z occurs, regardless of case.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is way simpler than this.

You need to `#include <ctype.h>` and just use the `isupper()` and `islower()`.

Go over each char of input and have 2 counters - `upper_counter`, `lower_counter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `X[i]` contains the count for both lower and upper-case letter `i`, as you are updating it for both cases. Also the final loop will print ALL of the letter counts. Not in the format you have defined in the beginning. Generally, it looks like the program is doing a *completely* different things from the requirements stated.