# Program that counts Uppercase and Lowercase letters in a String in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, int

so I want to make a code where you can find the number of upper and lowercase letters in a string (no spaces)
So I want something like this:

```
input:
HEllO
Output:
2 3
```

So what I have of code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int upper = 0, lower = 0;
char ch[80];
int i;

printf("\nEnter The String : ");
gets(ch);

i = 0;
while (ch[i] != '') {
  if (ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')
     upper++;
  if (ch[i] >= 'a' && ch[i] <= 'z')
     lower++;
  i++;
  }

  printf("%d %d", upper, lower);


  return (0);
  }
```

There is a problem with the code, but I cannot find the mistake. Can someone please fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `while (ch[i] != '')` should be `while (ch[i] != '\0')`

Comment: And what is the problem? Btw `''` is a synonym for `'\0'` ?

Comment: @luk32 No, `''` is not a synonym for `'\0'`. It is a syntax error and won't compile.

Comment: @luk32 I am afraid it's not. It shows this upon compilation-  `error: empty character constant`

Comment: This isn't the cause of your issue, but note that you should *never* use gets().  It doesn't get passed the length of your buffer, so if the input is more than 79 characters long, it will overflow the ch array, causing undefined behavior.  Instead, use fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), stdin);  Note that unlike gets, fgets will include the newline in the buffer if present, but that doesn't make a difference in your case since '\n' is not in [A-Z] or [a-z].

Comment: @Ray `This isn't the cause of your issue`, what makes you say that?

Comment: Because the empty character constant will cause this to fail to compile, and the gets will only cause undefined behavior once the program is running, so you never get to that error.  (By "this", I meant my comment about gets, not your comment about '')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Number of Uppercase and Lowercase Letters in a string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370850/count-number-of-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370850/count-number-of-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters-in-a-string-in-c asked the exact same question with the exact same input and output format earlier today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C a string always terminates with `'\0'`. The empty string `''` and the escape null character **are not identical**.

`while (ch[i] != '')` should be `while (ch[i] != '\0')`

Your program should work then.

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected code-**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int upper = 0, lower = 0;
    char ch[80];
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nEnter The String : ");
    fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), stdin);
    while (ch[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')
            upper++;
        if (ch[i] >= 'a' && ch[i] <= 'z')
            lower++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nuppercase letter(s): %d \nlowercase letter(s): %d", upper, lower);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I have used `fgets()` instead of `gets()` as the latter suffers from a buffer overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the expression ''.  A character constant must have something between the single quotes.  In this case, you want to test for end of string, so you would use the null character constant: '\0'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int upper = 0, lower = 0;
    char ch[80];
    int i;

    printf("\nEnter The String : ");

    fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), stdin);
    i = 0;
    while (ch[i] != '\0') {
        if (ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')
            upper++;
        if (ch[i] >= 'a' && ch[i] <= 'z')
            lower++;
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", upper, lower);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I also replaced gets with fgets.  You should never use gets(). It doesn't get passed the length of your buffer, so if the input is more than 79 characters long, it will overflow the ch array, causing undefined behavior. fgets takes a *size* argument and stops reading once it's read *size - 1*.  It also includes the newline in the resulting string if one is present in the input, which gets does not.

A better approach that works properly for all input lengths is to read the string in one character at a time, and not bother storing it, since all you care about is the count of upper and lower.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned upper = 0, lower = 0;
    printf("\nEnter The String : ");

    int c;
    while (EOF != (c = getchar())) {
        if ('\n' == c) break;

        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            upper++;
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            lower++;
    }
    printf("%u %u\n", upper, lower);

    return 0;
}
```